# TP4056 module parallel output

Tags: batteries, circuit-protection

this is my first time asked on stack exchange, please <s>bear</s> bare with me.
Anyway, I created portable monitor using multiple TP4056 as battery charger & protection circuit. But I'm not sure it's safe or not.

this is the wiring diagram :
[image]

[image]

why I wired this way? Apparently the monitor needs more than 5 Watt, and using 1 TP4056 can't give enough power. (the monitor needs 12 volt). So far my solution works, but I worried about the safety.

**what I'm asking is this solution safe?**

Thank you

edit 2:
To power up 12 volt monitor, I stepped up the output from TP 4056 (from around 3-4 volt) using XL6009 module to 12 volt. As you can see, the module located under the batteries.

Comment: +1 for saying `please bear with me` .... most people say "bare with me" .... lol

Comment: lol... my bad XD.
I want to say English is not my native language, but it's just an excuse.

Comment: I'm surprised it works if the monitor needs 12 V. In the absence of external power you'll only get about 4.3 V from the batteries. It looks perfectly safe though.

Comment: TP4056 has a cut-off at 2.5V, which is rather low. 3-3.3V is best. I’ve also observed TP4056 cutting power at too high load (don’t know the exact ampere value). A LVCO of 2.5V is not going to give you 1000-1200 charge cycles. 5W is a stretch for XL6009, mine can only go up to 4-5W. Does the XL6009 get hot?

Comment: the XL6009 modile is geeting hot, but not that bad (my smartphone is way hotter sometimes).
actually from my test, the power consumption around 6 watt (5.12v for 1.14A) . and sometimes spike to 7.2 watt (5.14v for 1.4A).

I already tried using 1 TP4056, but it doesen't provide enough power (the screen turned on-off) .
I tried using DIY powerbank circuit, it had same problem.

Comment: how do you charge the batteries?, you plug a usb to each usb female inputs?, or do you wired them in parallel?, how?

Comment: i linked all TP4056 charging together, so i just need plugin regular charger to one port.

Answer (score 3):

The cutoff voltage is a trade-off between maximum current capability and battery under-voltage protection, at high currents (which is your case)  the battery voltage can drop down to 2.5V even the battery is not over-discharged but this wasn't your question

There is nothing that forbids you to use this configuration, I actually used-it for a two batteries / two  TP4056 configuration.