# TP4056 keep shorting / dropping voltage when connected to XL6009 DC-DC converter. I found 2 solutions, which one is the best?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, tp4056

Here is the electronics, I took the picture after I cut the wires, the measurement being done before the wires being cut. [image: A = out +- of XL6009, B = in +- of XL6009, C = out +- of TP4056]

Here is the diagram
[image]

Basically, the voltage keeps dropping on C, from supposedly 4V to only 1V when I connect it to XL6009  DC-DC converter, without connecting the fan. Based on few searching, I discovered this post [TP4056 module shutdown problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359600/tp4056-module-shutdown-problem?newreg=9d14ace854814176a882936be10ec9fb) , and found 2 solutions.

1. Add more TP4056 and make them parallel (answer by Simon Dyer). They're dirt cheap anyway so I can afford few of them, but is it safe? And what's the diagram to connect them all properly?
2. Directly hook the battery into in +- of XL6009  DC-DC converter, with switch (Answer by Antonio51). However, again, is it safe? I don't think the batteries have protection in case something happen with the XL6009  DC-DC converter.

Comment: You need to provide some more information, such as the datasheet http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf and a schematic or sketch of what you are measuring.

Comment: Are you using ***XL6009 from HaoYu or XLsemi?*** XLSemi is the best. XL6009 180KHz 60V 5A Switching Current Boost DC/DC Converter Datasheet - HaoYu/ XLSemi
(1) https://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/XL6009/XL6009-DC-DC-Converter-Datasheet.pdf
(2) http://www.xlsemi.net/datasheet/XL6019%20datasheet-English.pdf

Comment: Did you get your ***TP4056 from eBay or AliEx/Amazon***? (1) https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-tp4056-lithium-battery-charge-module.html, TP4056 1A Standalone Linear Li-lon Battery Charger with Thermal (2) Regulation in SOP-8 - NanJing Top Power ASIC
http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf

Comment: Why you use TP4056? XL6009 already has built in over voltage and over current protection.  I think you can forget TP4056 and ***use a polyFuse for extra short circuit/over current. protection***.

Comment: XL6009 4A is an overkill. I would suggest to instead use the popular cheapy LM2596　3A LM2596 module

https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-lm2596-module.html

Comment: @tlfong01 I don't know, the local seller didn't specify where they bought it and what kind of brand it belongs.

Comment: @tlfong01 and for the module, then how can I charge the battery with? I use TP4056 for charging. And the LM2596, I'll look into it.

Comment: @PStechPaul here the diagram https://imgur.com/a/EtQtYi1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140866/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-david-mctravord).

Comment: Please also draw schematic diagram there's a tool if you edit your question

Comment: @VoltageSpike done, I forgot to add that

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

1. You need a charger (CCCV = Constant Current, Constant Voltage), not a power supply (CV only). The XL6009 DC-DC converter is not current limited
2. You **MUST** have a protector BMS (PCM) to protect each and every cells.

As you have it, your set-up is a house fire waiting top start. STOP NOW!

Comment: Thanks for the warning! I am aware of the fire risk, so I always keep the fire extinguisher nearby (https://imgur.com/a/66FCqm9), and also I am working semi outdoor (because the solder fume too). Anyway, I am still new to electronics, and this is some of my first "serious" project, so I still not having much knowledge about what charger that I need, how to connect them etc, so I just copying from the youtube about the wiring and the parts. In that mind, would you mind suggesting me which part should I get, and how to wire them properly? Thank you.